# No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up.user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I incorporated devise in my user model but when i try to sign up someone i get this error No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up.user"
I have the devise views and controllers in my app too. But when i click the sign up button i get that error.

this is my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }

  #resources :users  

  #resources :admin

  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
end
```

and  this is my form

### Sign up

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:     new_user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Please post your routes and form code.

Comment: Your signup form has the wrong url by the looks of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem, and struggled with what was up for a while. My solution might not have anything to do with your particular case, but worth a try.

In my view I had used erb's `button_to` tag to hit the `new_user_registration_path`:

```
<%= button_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %>
```

this was sending a POST request when the route is a GET request. Changing the `button_to` tag to a `link_to` tag solved it:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the route to:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

There's no need for the resource in the path you're using in your form. Simply take it out and it should look like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: new_user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```